# How to add an image view sharing between navigation bar and view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I had to add an image so that half of it is in the navigation bar and remaining is in the view.I know there is always a probability of adding two images,but i want to know is there any way to add an image view(only one)between the two?Now i know i can do this way ,

`[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];`

and also     `self.view addSubview:imageView`,but i need a single image view to be shared between the two

> ie the first half is in navigation bar and the remaning is in the view.can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Can't you add another layer onto it, half on nav bar and rest of on view?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible AFAIK. A view (including a UIImageView) can only have one superview. SO it's either a child of the UINavigationBar or one of the other view, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

with ios 7 you can use translucent navigations bars so that you can set the imageview in your view and it shines through the navbar :-)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @ShimonRachlenko ... yes, its an answer to his question. perhaps you don't understand it well :-)